# MSDeploy migrate only configuration from IIS 6 to 7

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, msdeploy

We have 19 websites, many of which have many "virtual" directories, on a IIS 6 server.  I am trying to migrate the whole thing over to IIS 7 on a different server.

Following the instructions on http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/427/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-70/ I attempted the following command line execution:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm/w3svc -dest:package=D:\Temp\Sites.zip > D:\temp\WebDeployPackage.log
```

It appeared to be working until I got a "There is not enough space on the disk" error.  The D drive, which you'll notice is the target location for the package and the log has plenty of space (all the resources for the websites are about 5gb, the drive has 200+).  Though the C drive is of limited size (6Gb), so that might be the problem.

Anyway, I figure the best bet was to try and do a migration of settings/configurations *only*, not the actual resources.  We can easily deploy the resources to the new server with our NAnt build scripts, so that's not an issue.  Getting all the correct configurations moved over, however, would be challenging to do manually.

So, is there a way to export/package only the configuration/options of the IIS 6 server using msdeploy (or any other tool?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think I might have found it: as described here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1159017.aspx

Note the addition of -disabledLink option:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm/w3svc -disableLink:contentExtension -dest:package=D:\Temp\Sites.zip > D:\temp\WebDeployPackage.log
```