# IIS 6 to IIS 7 sites migration & configuration

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, sites

I am migrating multiple sites with application pools in order to do this. I need to create a package, and while I try to create the package I get an error stating:

`"Error: there is not enough space on the disk" 
ERROR count: 1`

I clearly have more than 500GBs on the destination disk and even tried another disk to be certain its not a space issue. The webdeploypackage.log file gets created and grows to a mighty 3Mbs even, but no package.zip gets created. My syntax is listed below please offer any help you could.

`msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/1 -enableLink:contentExtension -dest:package=E:\DevSites.zip > E:\WebDeployPackage.log`

Answer (score 0):

sites i used to get my gudiance:

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1614-iis6-to-iis7-migration

[MSDeploy migrate only configuration from IIS 6 to 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601862/msdeploy-migrate-only-configuration-from-iis-6-to-7)

syntax: creating package on the source IIS6

msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/1 -disableLink:contentExtension -enableLink:AppPoolExtension -dest:package=E:\Sites.zip > E:\WebDeployPackage_Dev2.log

syntax: recall package on the destination server IIS7

C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>ms deploy -verb:sync -source:package=c:\Sites.zip -dest:metakey=lm/w3svc/1

*important note
Using powercopy or robocopy the content(data) must be copied over from source to destination separately.